# File Transfer in Android on WiFi using TCP causes the app to crash if file size is too big

Tags: android, tcp, wifi, large-files, file-transfer

I was trying to transfer a music file from one android phone to another by having a server app running on one phone to send the file and a client app on the other to receive the file. I opened a TCP socket to establish the connection and transfer the bytes. However, as I increase the file size, the server keeps sending the files when the client is still blocking while  receiving. This results in chunks of data missing, till finally the app crashes. I tried to space the sending action by sleeping the thread after every send so that the receive buffer doesn't overflow, but think this is a wasteful approach. Can anyone suggest a better way to coordinate between send and receive such that reliably an mp3 file of size approx 5 Mb can be sent?

Thanks,
Swetha

```
    private BufferedInputStream in = null;
    private BufferedOutputStream output = null;
    ReceiveBytes str2;
    private FileOutputStream out3;
    private Socket clientsocket;

    try 
      { 
      clientsocket= new Socket("192.168.1.70",9864);
      }
    catch(ActivityNotFoundException e) 
      {
     Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());            
      } 
    catch(Exception e) 
      {
      Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());           
      }

    try 
      {
      out3= new FileOutputStream(path,true);
      } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
      {
       Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());              
      }

    try
         {
             in = new BufferedInputStream(clientsocket.getInputStream());
             output = new BufferedOutputStream(out3);
             str2 = new ReceiveBytes(clientsocket,out3);
             str2.copyfile();
             clientsocket.close(); 
             out3.close();
         }
    catch(IOException e)
         {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage()); 
         }
     catch(Exception e1)
         {
           Log.e1(TAG, e1.getMessage());    
         }
```

I have include a snipet of my code. ReceiveBytes is a user defined class. It is as follows.

```
    public class ReceiveBytes
        {
     public ReceiveBytes(){};
     private Socket src_file;
     private FileOutputStream dest_file;
     private int MaxTransferbytes = 1024;


     public ReceiveBytes (Socket Src, FileOutputStream Dest)
     {
    src_file = Src;
    dest_file =Dest;
         }


      public int copyfile () throws Exception 
      {
      BufferedInputStream in = null;
      BufferedOutputStream output = null;
      int off=0;
      int received =0;
      int k;
      byte[] buffer = new byte[2*MaxTransferbytes];


      try 
      {
      in = new BufferedInputStream(src_file.getInputStream());
      output = new BufferedOutputStream(dest_file);

      while(in.available()>0)
      {
         k = in.available();
             if(k>MaxTransferbytes)
             {
             try
                      {
                   received = in.read(buffer,0,(MaxTransferbytes));
                       output.write(buffer,0,received);
                      }
                 catch(IOException e1)
                      {
                       Log.e1(TAG, e1.getMessage());    
                      }
               }
             else
             {
                 try
                      {
                   received = in.read(buffer,0,(k));
                       output.write(buffer,0,received);
                      }
                  catch(IOException e1)
                      {
                       Log.e1(TAG, e1.getMessage());    
                      }
              }

            }


    } 
    catch(Exception e) 
    {
       System.out.printf(e.getMessage());
     } 

      return(1);
     }
     }
```

Here, in every iteration, I transfer 1024 bytes. So a large file needs quite a few iterations to copy the file. However, this causes the app to crash. Any suggestions as to how I can do this without making the app crash? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you using an ASyncTask to download the files?

Comment: MMS, Email, Push file to cloud and download from there on other side. All seem like better options than sending the bytes through a TCP stream. But also we can't offer much specific help if you don't post your code.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will post the code and explain my question.

Comment: Is there any reason why you believe that sending bytes through a TCP stream is not a very good option? I tried doing this using a UDP stream, but established reliability by my own means. However, that reduced my throughput a lot. I was wondering if there was anyway of reaching high throughput using a TCP stream?